# Camera2 API OIS Issue

Tags: android, api, camera, blob, android-camera2

I have a Huawei Nova Plus device. I enabled Camera2 API with build prop edit, and almost works fine, but ois don't work. I think some libs need to have some fixes. But i don't even know what libs have an influence on camera ois. Maybe some expert users can help me to get camera ois to work with camera2 api.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work immediately after enabling the non-default HAL, it's probably not feasible to enable without source access to the HAL libraries.

It sounds like a feature that wasn't completed.

Comment: And there's nothing you can do about it?

Comment: Unlikely. I mean, there's some possibility there's a system property you could change the value of, or similar.  So you could run strings on the HAL libraries and see if there's a string that might be a system property that affects OIS, but it's a really unlikely thing.

Comment: Can you please explain how to run strings on the HAL libraries?